# Changing location of objects for infinite runner using pooling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a game where an object is to fly upwards infinitely. I am pooling a list of objects when the game first starts that are clouds that are above each other. As I pass them and they are no longer visible I want to take the bottom most object and move it to the very top of the last object that was created. Then I take the next object and move it above that one. I have:

```
    void Update () {

    lastPosition = pool.startPosition;

    GameObject ObjAltitude = GameObject.Find ("Rocket");
    startGame startGameScript = ObjAltitude.GetComponent <startGame> ();
    altitude = startGameScript.altitude;

    if (altitude > 100) 
    {
        pool.pool [0] [0].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        Vector2 currentPosition = pool.pool [0] [0].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        lastPosition = currentPosition;
        print ("ALTITUDE OVER 100");

    }


}
```

I want to use either time or altitude to trigger when to move the one below. The way I have it setup is once my altitude reaches 100 take the bottom most object and move it above the top. I can not think of a way to step through and move each one once I hit a certain altitude. I do not want to create a bunch of if statements for each altitude trigger because I want this to be an infinite loop. Any ideas?

There are a total of 5 objects that I want to rotate through:

```
pool [0] [0]
pool [0] [1]
pool [0] [2]
pool [0] [3]
pool [0] [4]
```

This is a game where an object is to fly upwards infinitely. I am pooling a list of objects when the game first starts that are clouds that are above each other. As I pass them and they are no longer visible I want to take the bottom most object and move it to the very top of the last object that was created. Then I take the next object and move it above that one. I have:

```
    void Update () {

    lastPosition = pool.startPosition;

    GameObject ObjAltitude = GameObject.Find ("Rocket");
    startGame startGameScript = ObjAltitude.GetComponent <startGame> ();
    altitude = startGameScript.altitude;

    if (altitude > 100) 
    {
        pool.pool [0] [0].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        Vector2 currentPosition = pool.pool [0] [0].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        lastPosition = currentPosition;
        print ("ALTITUDE OVER 100");

    }


}
```

I want to use either time or altitude to trigger when to move the one below. The way I have it setup is once my altitude reaches 100 take the bottom most object and move it above the top. I can not think of a way to step through and move each one once I hit a certain altitude. I do not want to create a bunch of if statements for each altitude trigger because I want this to be an infinite loop. Any ideas?

There are a total of 5 objects that I want to rotate through:

```
pool [0] [0]
pool [0] [1]
pool [0] [2]
pool [0] [3]
pool [0] [4]
```

Based on serhiyb's answer I modified my code as such:

```
    void Update () {


    GameObject ObjAltitude = GameObject.Find ("Rocket");
    startGame startGameScript = ObjAltitude.GetComponent <startGame> ();
    altitude = startGameScript.altitude;
    v2Altitude = new Vector2(0,altitude);
    int poolIndex = (((int)altitude)/100) % 5/*pool size goes here*/;

    //pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
    pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = v2Altitude + new Vector2 (0, 100);
    Vector2 currentPosition = pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = v2Altitude + new Vector2 (0, 100);
    //lastPosition = currentPosition;
}
```

This is working which is great but something is happening that I don't fully understand. This is causing my first object that has been created to move with the camera. However, aside from that object moving, which I can't see in the camera, all the objects are being moved in front. So it is working but why is this one object moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  void Update () {

    lastPosition = pool.startPosition;

    GameObject ObjAltitude = GameObject.Find ("Rocket");
    startGame startGameScript = ObjAltitude.GetComponent <startGame> ();
    altitude = startGameScript.altitude;

    int poolIndex = (((int)altitude)/100) % 5/*pool size goes here*/;

        pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        Vector2 currentPosition = pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = lastPosition + new Vector2 (0, 100);
        lastPosition = currentPosition;
  }
```

Comment: That is causing my objects to go ridiculously high and continue to rise. The y coords start between around 100-1000 and this causes my objects to go above almost 100k on the y coords.

Comment: Try to set object position based on altitude. Something like pool.pool [0] [poolIndex].transform.position = altitude + new Vector2 (0, 100) instead of tracking currentPosition and lastPosition.

Comment: if i set the altitude var in it it makes my object go up as the altitude increases

Comment: You should use same rounding technique when setting position based on altitude 100*((int)altitude)/100). This will ensure that position is updated each 100 units instead of on each update.